# php filling jagged array 3 columns 3 rows

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, jagged-arrays

I have this array (my results from database)

```
$nums = array("one","two","three",....,"nine");
```

or

```
$nums = array("one","two","three","four");
```

and I want to fill a jagged array with these values.
My jagged array should be like this :

```
$kb = [
   ['one','two','three'],
   ['four','five','six'],
   ['seven','eight','nine']
];
```

or

```
$kb = [
   ['one','two','three'],
   ['four',' ',' ']
];
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_chunk` will mostly do the job,

```
$kb = array_chunk($nums, 3);
```

but it won't fill the final sub-array with blanks if the input array doesn't divide evenly.
i.e., `array_chunk` as-is will produce:

```
$kb = [
   ['one','two','three'],
   ['four']
];
```

rather than your desired output.

You can union the last item with an array of blanks to fix that.

```
$kb[count($kb)-1] = end($kb) + ['','',''];
```

(It's okay to execute that unconditionally; if the input array *does* divide evenly it won't change anything.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [array_chunk()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) method

```
$nums = array("one","two","three","four");

$nums = array_chunk($nums, 3);
```